# Git "You have not concluded your merge" and nothing to commit?

Tags: git

Whenever I try to push in Git I get this:

```
You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
```

Running `git status` I get:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Or running `git ls-files -u` I get nothing.

Running `git add .`and trying again makes no difference.

What's up?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Okay I finally found answer: `git commit -m "Test"` apparently fixed this. The result was an empty commit with no changes whatsoever. Even Github shows an empty commit, but it works.

Comment: For me this showed up as the commit marking the merge point, so a message like "Merging dev into master" would be more appropriate than "Test".

Comment: Wow. Now can anyone explain why this works but `git commit` does not?

Comment: wow nice one it worked

Answer (score 84):

Did you end up with an empty merge commit (two parents) or just an empty commit? In the latter case, you could have deleted `.git/MERGE_HEAD`.

**Update:** Rather than delete `MERGE_HEAD` by hand, you could also use `git merge --abort` ([as of git 1.7.4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35d2fffdb857836cc46f5a4ada525a246ddd5e11)) or `git reset --merge` ([as of git 1.6.2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e8eceab73e9f6a1e9349b1c14d4db0c035ac1ba)).

It's also worth mentioning that at least as of git 1.8.3 (maybe earlier?) you should see a `status` message like this if an actual merge is in progress and needs to be committed (if you specified `--no-commit`, for example):

```
# On branch master
# All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
#   (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

If you don't see this and still get the `MERGE_HEAD` warning, something is messed up and you should probably just `--abort` to get back to a clean state.

**Additional Detail from Comments**

During a merge, git creates a MERGE_HEAD file in the root of the .git folder (next to HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, probably FETCH_HEAD, etc) to track information about the merge in progress (specifically, the SHA(s) of the commit(s) being merged into the current HEAD). If you delete that, Git will no longer think a merge is in progress. Obviously, if a merge really is in progress then you wouldn't want to delete this file.

Comment: This solution seems more convenient for me than committing empty merges since this happens so often with git.

Comment: Thanks for this. Wish I really understood it. When I have time, guess I'll peruse the docs.

Comment: During a merge, git creates a `MERGE_HEAD` file in the root of the `.git` folder (next to `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, probably `FETCH_HEAD`, etc) to track information about the merge in progress (specifically, the SHA(s) of the commit(s) being merged into the current `HEAD`). If you delete that, Git will no longer think a merge is in progress. Obviously, if a `merge` really _is_ in progress then you wouldn't want to delete this file.

Answer (score 27):

Use `git reset` command, without parameters.
[Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Comment: For me the parameter `--merge` was necessary.